# Does change in size of video frames affect the performance of object detection model

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I've trained an object detection model on tensorflow SSD mobilenet V2 using 1000 images of a single object class, and since the quantity of image is low the performance is below average, but considerable.
The resolution of images were 1920*1020.
Now when I do inferencing on a Region of interest on the video frames which is about 60%-70% smaller than the full size image the performance becomes terrible.

Should I train the model on images of the Region of Interest, or should go ahead with the full size image.
What will be the right approach.

Comment: please clarify: performance meaning *quality* of results? or performance meaning *execution speed*? -- consider asking this on a stackexchange for ML/AI concepts. this site here is for programming. https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic

Comment: Performance = accuracy of results, thank you for the link @ChristophRackwitz